# TypeError: parse() takes 1 positional argument but 6 were given

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, strptime

I am trying to run below code but everytime I am getting a typing error.

```
def parse(x):
    return datetime.strptime(x, '%Y %-m %-d %-H:%-M:%-S')

dataset = read_csv('ID1887011.csv', delimiter=",", parse_dates = [['year', 
'month','day','hours','minutes', 'seconds']], 
               index_col=0, date_parser=parse)
```

Comment: See the pandas docs "Pandas will try to call date_parser in three different ways, advancing to the next if an exception occurs: 1) Pass one or more arrays (as defined by parse_dates) as arguments; 2) concatenate (row-wise) the string values from the columns defined by parse_dates into a single array and pass that; and 3) call date_parser once for each row using one or more strings (corresponding to the columns defined by parse_dates) as arguments." https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 1):

Hi I made some changes in the code and now its working.

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('ID1887011.csv', delimiter=",", index_col='datetime', 
parse_dates = {'datetime': [1,2,3,4,5,6]}, date_parser=lambda x: 
pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y %m %d %H %M %S'))
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Code with error]

[image: Code without error]

First image is error code and second is correct code. You don't need to change the code. In your code i think you import datetime instead you need to from datetime import datetime